# como gerar um index.js a cada build - WebPack

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack

Estou trabalhando em um projeto nuxt/vue.js e aplicando a metodologia do design atomic, então eu terei muuuittos componentes, em diferentes pastas, exemplo:

```
├── components
│   ├── quarks
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── bosons
│   │   └── GridLayout.vue
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── atoms
│   │   └── ButtonStyle.vue
│   │   └── InputStyle.vue
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── molecules
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── organisms
│   │   └── ...
│   ├── templates
│   │   └── ...
└─────
```

eu gostaria de fazer importações nomeadas, exemplo:

```
import { ButtonStyle, InputStyle } from '@/components/atoms/'
```

mas pra isso dar certo eu precisaria ter um index.js dentro de cada pasta exportando componente por componente, exemplo

```
├── components
│   ├── atoms
│   │   └── ButtonStyle.vue
│   │   └── InputStyle.vue
│   │   └── index.js
└─────
```

e no `index.js`

```
export { default as ButtonStyled } from './ButtonStyled.vue'
export { default as InputStyle } from './InputStyle.vue'
```

então tudo funciona!

Mas fazer esse trabalho manualmente pode ser uma tarefa muito cansativa... Toda vez que criar, deletar, renomear um componente, teria que atualizar o `index.js` da sua respectiva pasta.

Então penso em fazer essa exportação de forma dinâmica.

Eu pensei em criar um Plugin do Webpack e utilizar os Hooks para executar algum script a cada build `(que acontece quando um arquivo é alterado)` que faça esse trabalho de varrer as pastas dentro de `components` e gerar um `index.js` `pra cada pasta` exportando os componentes.

Mas não faço ideia de como fazer esse script..

alguém poderia me ajudar?

Agradeço desde já!

Comment: Por que você não deixa de criar esse arquivo `index`? Basta importar diretamente do arquivo... Se você tá perdendo produtividade, não vejo motivo para se dar ao trabalho de fazer algo assim. PS: Minha opinião.

Comment: @LuizFelipe, pretendo me aperfeiçoar em Atomic Design, para esse tipo de arquitetura que tem muitos componentes e muitas importações, seria interessante uma sintaxe enxuta na hora de fazer importações, pois faria importações agrupadas por tipo de component, o objetivo é refatoração e legibilidade.

Comment: Acho que o que quer é um CLI tipo do Angular, lá você tem o comando `ng g c` que cria um componente e possui uma opção onde você pode especificar um pacote de template (por padrão usa o do próprio Angular, mas você pode colocar o seu), não sei se o Vue tem um CLI, se não tiver, pode fazer um

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Utilizei um hook que é executado apenas uma única vez na compilação, com `chokidar` fico escutando alterações dentro do meu diretório de componentes.

```
compiler.hooks.entryOption.tap('MyPlugin', (context, entry) => {
  // generates index.js
  // Watch a directory with chokidar 
});
```

Como irei utilizar isso em vários projetos, transformei isso em uma library, um plugin para webpack, quem quiser, segue o link!

### [Weback Plugin - named-exports](https://github.com/yungsilva19/named-exports)